# make first 2 headers sticky

Tags: html, css, angular, sticky

I have a table with 2 headers and I'm trying to make both the headers sticky, with the below coding only the top header is sticky.

```
<div class="ft-table" style="overflow: scroll;height: 60vh;>
  <div role="table header" class="ft-table_header" style="position: sticky; top: 0px;">
    <div class="ft-tableactions">
      <a href="#add">ADD</a>
      <a href="#delete">Delete</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div role="table body" class="ft-table_body" style="min-height: 50vh;overflow: scroll;">
    <div class="ft-table-view">
      <table class="ft-table ft-table--is-hoverable">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>
              <div class="ft-form-control">
                <label class="checkbox">
                  <span class="checkbox__icon"></span><span
                      class="checkbox__text"></span>
                </label>
              </div>
            </th>
            <th *ngFor="let column of displayedColumns">{{column}}</th>
            <th></th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr *ngFor="let data of backupData">
            <td>
              <div class="ft-form-control">
                <label class="checkbox">
                  <span class="checkbox__icon"></span><span
                      class="checkbox__text"></span>
                </label>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td *ngFor="let col of displayedColumns">
              <div class="ft-form-control">
                <div class="control__input-group">
                  <p *ngIf="checkIfCorrect(col)">{{getdata(data,col)}}</p>
                 </div>
                </div>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
```

I've given inline CSS to make first header sticky `style="position: sticky; top: 0px;"`. While in CSS class I've added the below lines to make my 2nd row sticky but unfortunately it doesn't work.

```
thead tr th {
position: sticky;
top: 25px;
}
```

Whatever value I give for top, its not sticky. What am I doing wrong ? Is there any other way of making the first 2 headers sticky.

Comment: Did you try this one because sometime browser read that property also position: webkit-sticky;